# michael hartl tutorial> the BUNDLER part

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby and ruby on rails also programming . I have been following michael hartl tutorial and i have diffiulty with bundle section the link: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-bundler
i have tried following it but on my gitbash comes out

```
$ bundle update
  Gemfile syntax error:
  gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
             ^
```

and  i have changed the >subl Gemfile< to :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'
# ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end


gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks' , '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

iam using a windows 8.1 64x based system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line above you are missing a close quote:

```
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'   <---- missing the close quote here
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
```